# React fetch giving me this error: Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have set the proxy in create-react-app to the root URL like so:

```
"proxy": "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1",
```

So no CORS issues...

Then I'm performing a simple fetch and passing in the headers including the content type and accept set to application.json

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/entries/en/ace', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        app_id: 'API_ID',
        app_key: 'APP_KEY',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('====================================');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('====================================');
      });
  }
```

Seems to work in Postman just fine... Just set the headers, send a get request and get the response... I can do it with a chrome extension and it works fine... What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure you're getting JSON as your response?

Comment: Yes, I simply rewrote the exact same thing. I'm comparing it now - identical - and it works.... ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug first 'then' clause?
I would also suggest not to use fetch, but instead something like axios - https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios